# Using __shfl_xor in my CUDA kernel but getting error when compiling

Tags: compiler-errors, cuda, nvidia, nvcc

I am trying to use __shfl_xor in my kernel but when I try to compile it, I get the error "error: identifier "__shfl_xor" is undefined". I am aware that you have to set the flag `arch=compute_30,code=sm_30` to use it but I have already added that in my CMakeLists.txt

Here is my kernel:

```
__global__ void dummy_kernel()
{
    int x = 5;
    int y = 10;
    __shfl_xor(x, y);
}
```

Here is the output from the compiler:

```
/filepath/kernel_file.cu(13): error: identifier "__shfl_xor" is undefined
```

Here is what my CMakeLists.txt looks like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)

if(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
    set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Release" CACHE STRING "Choose the type of build, options are: Debug Release RelWithDebInfo MinSizeRel." FORCE)
endif()

find_package(CUDA REQUIRED)

cuda_add_executable(CasHashing3D
    MatchPairGPU.cu
)
set(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS "${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS} -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30")
set(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS "${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS} -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35")
set_property(TARGET CasHashing3D PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 11)
set_property(TARGET CasHashing3D PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

configure_file(job.sh.in job.sh @ONLY)
```

The makefile generated by CMake is too large to paste in the question so here is [a link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B12kHCifNddSV0xYdkxFVUc4dkE) to the file.

Comment: What do the full `CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS` look like? You are adding to them, but likely you already have an architecture in there that doesn't support shuffle intrinsics.

Comment: @tera I have Tesla K20Xm which is 3.5 so it should be okay. 3 or above is required. 

CMakeLists.txt sets  `CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS` to the value  `-gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30`.

Comment: @talonmies I have edited the answer to include a simple kernel and also the error from the compiler.

Comment: @talonmies Please check now.

Comment: We still haven't seen any compiler commands, but it is obvious that your build system is also building for compute 2x targets

Comment: @talonmies I see. I have added the make file that is generated by CMake in the answer. It's not clear why it's compiling for 2x targets.

Comment: I don't believe that is the correct Makefile.  It is a toplevel makefile generated by CMake, but it invokes lower-level makefiles to actually build targets.  The one you are interested in may possibly be called Makefile2, and/or you could also just increase CMake verbosity (google it) and copy and paste the actual make output into your question, it should include the compile commands as well as the error output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow I changed my CMakeLists.txt to the following and it worked, I have no idea why. I will update the answer once I figure out what I was doing wrong.

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -pthread -lpthread")
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
project(CasHashing3D)
find_package(CUDA REQUIRED)
# Pass options to NVCC
set(
    CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS
    ${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS};
    -O3 -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35;
    )

cuda_add_executable(CasHashing3D
    Main.cc
)

set_property(TARGET CasHashing3D PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 11)
set_property(TARGET CasHashing3D PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
configure_file(job.sh.in job.sh @ONLY)
```

Answer (score 1):

You set to CUDA architecture 35, which supports __shfl_xor()
Fermi GPUs don't support that instruction (ie architectures 20 and 21)